# Why am I getting a syntax error?

Tags: php, syntax-error

The following snippet gives 2 syntax errors where I check the condition in the `if` block

```
public function __construct() {
    if(isset($_POST['update_email')) { # First syntax error
        $this->email = $_POST['update_email'];
    }

    if(isset($_POST['password')) { # Second syntax error
        $this->password = $_POST['password'];
    }
}
```

I am unable to spot a syntax error. What is it ?

Comment: What syntax error are you getting? Does it show a line? A character? PLease inlcude the complete error.

Comment: @Nanne I am using dreamweaver and it doesn't show any error but highlights it

Comment: Hi there. If one of the below answers helped you, please do accept it (to do so, click the tick mark to the left of the answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missing the closing-brackets for the `$_POST` variables:

This line:

```
 if(isset($_POST['update_email')) {
```

Should be:

```
 if(isset($_POST['update_email'])) {
```

Same for the password-line too.

Answer (score 2):

You miss a closing `]` on the lines.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
if(isset($_POST['update_email']))
```

you are missing "]" closing tag

Comment: Sorry ....in fast typing I made mistake and didnt noticed...now it fine

Comment: In fact mine is first ans but due to small thing I lose it

Comment: Welcome to the Internet :)